# What is the name of a test presenting words in different colors?

Tags: terminology, experimental-psychology, test, color

What's the name of this psychological test where you.

1. Read and pronounce words in three colors (red, blue, green). - Words and colors match. - Say word and color (which are the same).
2. As above - Words and color now do not match. Say the color. - If the word is in a circle - Then say the written name.
3. As above - now words and colors do not match - alter (even and odd) between saying the color of the word and saying written word.

I have myself taken the test. Perhaps I remember some things wrong.

Comment: this is the best online implementation of Stroop test I've seen http://cognitivefun.net/test/2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an experiment testing the [Stroop effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect), named after John Ridley Stroop who studied it in 1935, and often called a Stroop experiment. It is a classic and well understood experiment and has now become a [neuropsychological test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuropsychological_test) for use in clinical settings, usually called the Stroop test.

Answer (score 6):

The three levels of the [Stroop test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect) you describe are the following:

1. Congruent stimuli
2. Incongruent stimuli
3. Incongruent stimuli alternated with the [Reverse Stroop effect](http://www.swarthmore.edu/SocSci/fdurgin1/ReverseStroop/PBRStroop.html)